# Oauth redirects to accounts.google

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, oauth

I use Oauth 2.0 to send e-mail on my site. I downloaded JSON from Gmail console and use it to send e-mail.

But when I try to send it, it opens https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount page.

How can I use OAUTH on my site without redirect to accounts.google page?